# Firefox iMacros loop until value is not found

Tags: firefox, loops, imacros

I am using [iMacros for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/), and I want to loop until I can't find the value, since each page is different. How can i do this?

Comment: **Much** more information is needed to properly answer your question.  Show us your code that you have so far, and be more specific as to what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that inside Imacros. LOOP must have a max value, it can't go forever. Write a javascript instead with a while loop and inside that loop launch the Imacro script with the value you search and make it return the result.

```
var searchValue = "blabla"
var found = false;
while(!found)
var ret;
ret = iimSet("searchValue", searchValue);
ret = iimPlay("myScript.iim");
/* Check for error */
if (ret = 1) {
 /* if no error we found it*/   
 found = true;}
else {
err = iimGetLastError();
/* we check if it is different than the error for Tag not found -921; else we go*/
    if (err !== -921) alert("Other error");
};
```